# Why rubocop vaidates excluded directories?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubocop

I use rubocop-rails gem and I ant to ignore some folders but it doesn't work. My rubocop.yml file looks like:

```
AllCops:
  Exclude:
    - 'db/**/*'
    - 'config/**/*'
    - 'bin/**/*'
    - 'app/mailers/**/*'
    - 'app/jobs/**/*'
    - 'app/channels/**/*'
    - 'config.ru'
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `.rubocop.yml`, not `rubocop.yml`. Also, `.rubocop.yml` should be in the correct directory, which is your project directory, and for example not home directory. In other words, `.rubocop.yml`, `db/` , `config/` should all be on the same level.

Otherwise, this yml chunk looks good.
See also: [RuboCop
Configuration](https://docs.rubocop.org/rubocop/configuration.html)